# Query View doesn't return any values in couchdb

Tags: java, couchdb, ektorp

I have  a view defined as:

```
function(doc) 
{ 
    if (doc.type="user")
    {
        emit([doc.uid, doc.groupid], null);
    } 
}
```

In Java code, I have written

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
keys.add("93");
keys.add("23");
ViewQuery q = createQuery("getProfileInfo").descending(true).keys(keys).includeDocs(true);
ViewResult vr = db.queryView(q);
List<Row> rows = vr.getRows();
for (Row row : rows) {
  System.out.println("Key--->"+row.getKey());
  System.out.println("Value--->"+key);
}
```

My code always returns 0 rows - what have I missed?

Comment: While cleaning up the formatting of your code, I noticed that your map function is doing an assignment (=) rather than a comparison (==). That should be the first thing you fix.

Comment: To anyone who has enough privileges to do so, could you please add a tag for [ektorp](http://code.google.com/p/ektorp/), the CouchDB Java library that is being used in the code above?

Comment: Could you post the raw JSON results from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the code to

```
ComplexKey keys = ComplexKey.of(“93”,”23”);
ViewQuery q = createQuery("getProfileInfo").descending(true).key(keys).includeDocs(true); 
ViewResult vr = db.queryView(q); 
List<Row> rows = vr.getRows(); 
for (Row row : rows) { 
  System.out.println("Key--->"+row.getKey()); 
  System.out.println("Value--->"+row.getValue()); 
}
```

and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a type mismatch, but it's impossible to tell for sure without seeing the view's rows. So, if I'm wrong please post an example row from your view.

'keys' is encoded to JSON before it is sent to CouchDB. You're adding two *strings* - "93" and "23" - but I'm guessing they're actually integers in the documents. In JSON, a string and an integer are encoded differently. A pair of strings is encoded to ["93", "23"] and a pair of integers is encoded to [93, 23].

If I'm correct then 'keys' should be defined as List<Integer> (or however that looks in Java).

Comment: When I query like this from browser I get the results as below http://localhost:5984/testdb/_design/TestUserDoc/_view/getProfileInfo?key=["93","23"] Result: {"total_rows":483,"offset":461,"rows":[ {"id":"16","key":["93","23"],"value":null} ]} But in Java I always get 0 rows. I have stored all fields as String in couchdb.

Comment: I changed the code to the following and it works now ComplexKey keys = ComplexKey.of(“93”,”23”); ViewQuery q = createQuery("getProfileInfo").descending(true).key(keys).includeDocs(true); ViewResult vr = db.queryView(q); List<Row> rows = vr.getRows(); for (Row row : rows) { System.out.println("Key--->"+row.getKey()); System.out.println("Value--->"+row.getValue()); }